# Notation for set of arbitrarily many dice rolls.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of outcomes for a single dice roll is given by:

\begin{equation}
[6] = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}
\end{equation}

The set of outcomes for $n$ dice rolls is given by:

\begin{equation}
[6]^n = \{ (x_i,\ldots,x_n)|x_i \in [6], i \in [n]\}
\end{equation}

What's the notation for the set of outcomes for arbitrarily many dice rolls?

\begin{equation}
\Omega = \{ (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),\ldots \}
\end{equation}

Also, for some $\omega \in \Omega$ what's the notation to get the number of die rolled? Is it $|(1,6)| = 2$?

Comment: For your first question, what about $\Omega:=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N} [6]^k$?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm just confused as to what's the difference between $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [6]^n$ and $\prod_{n=1}^\infty [6]^n$.

Comment: The symbol $\cup$ means "union of sets", and the symbol $\prod$ means "product" of different things. By example $\prod_{k=1}^nk=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n$. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)).

Comment: You may use the notation $([6])^{<\omega}$. For a set $A$, $A^{<\omega}$ denotes a collection of all finite sequences over $A$. However in your case there may be a confusion, because the notation $[A]^{<\omega}$ denotes the set of all finite subsets of $A$.